# Are there minimum uncertainty wavepackets other than the Gaussian wavepackets?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Could you mention some examples of  minimum uncertainty quantum wavepackets other than Gaussian wavepackets, if there is any?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states#Quantum_mechanical_definition) wiki page

Comment: @BySymmetry A coherent state is a Gaussian wavepacket, isn't it?